# Yii 2.0 dropDownList not populated with database data

Tags: php, yii, yii2

Trying to make a drop down list in my view that is populated with data from a database table called "Category".
However this is not working and nothing is getting populated.

**Controllers\CasesController:**

```
public function actionIndex()
{

    $searchModel = new CaseSearch();  
    $allCategory = new Category;
    $allCategory = Category::findAllCategories();

    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

    $post_obj = Yii::$app->request->post();

    $category=1;
    if(isset($post_obj['CaseSearch']['category'])){
       $category = $post_obj['CaseSearch'];
       $dataProvider = $searchModel->searchByCategory($category);   
    }

    $searchModel->category = $category;

    return $this->render('index', [
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'post' => $post_obj,
        'allCategory' => $allCategory
    ]);
}
```

**models\Category:**

```
class Category extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
public $id;
public $name;

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public static function tableName()
{
    return 'Category';
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['id'], 'integer'],
        [['name'], 'required'],
        //[['LastEdited', 'Published'], 'safe'],
        [['name'], 'string', 'max' => 45]
    ];
}

public static function findAllCategories()
{
    Category::find()->indexBy('id')->all();
    return self::find();


}
```

**View:**

```
echo $form->field($searchModel, 'newcategory')
    ->dropDownList(
        $allCategory           // Flat array ('id'=>'label')

);
```

Any idea why this is not working?

Comment: You should fix `findAllCategories()`  which actually return an ActiveQuery object...

Comment: i'm not sure what to change it to

Answer (score 0):

Change these to lines

```
$allCategory = new Category;
$allCategory = Category::findAllCategories();
```

to:

```
$allCategory = Category::find()->all();
```

and

```
echo $form->field($searchModel, 'newcategory')
->dropDownList(
    $allCategory           // Flat array ('id'=>'label')
);
```

to:

```
echo $form->field($searchModel, 'newcategory')
          ->dropDownList(
              ArrayHelper::map($allCategory, 'id', 'name')
            )
?>
```

Comment: When i do this the dropdownlist is just blank @Jorgen